# Rails - Using for loop in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm having some problems accessing specific indexes when iterating through a for loop in my view.

The code below is working fine to access the first element, however, I'm getting errors when trying to use the (element) block in place of 0.

@word contains an array of hashes

```
<!-- loop through word elements -->
<% @word.each do |element|  %>

    <!-- display word -->
    <h1>  <%= @word[0]["word"] %>   </h1>

    <!-- display definition -->
    <p>   <%= @word[0]["text"] %>   </p>

<% end %>
```

I have a similar loop in my model file which works perfect for returning the array of hashes.

```
  # create an empty response array for loop below
  response = []

  search.each do |element|
    # Get back the first hash containing word information
    # Without .first returns an array of hashes with multiple definitions for single word
    response << Word.get_definitions(element).first
  end

  # return array of hashes containing information for each word
  return response
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are treating `element` as "`index` in a for loop".  `element` is the actual array element at each iteration.  So if an array contains "a", "b", "C" elements then element in `array.each do |element|` holds "a", "b", "c" respectively on each iteration within the block.

Update your `each` block to:

```
<!-- loop through word elements -->
<% @word.each do |element|  %>
    <!-- display word -->
    <h1>  <%= element["word"] %>   </h1>

    <!-- display definition -->
    <p>   <%= element["text"] %>   </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you holding in @word but you can do try this

```
<% @word.each do |element|  %>

<!-- display word -->
<h1>  <%= element.word %>   </h1>

<!-- display definition -->
<p>   <%= element.text %>   </p>
```